# SapUI5 exchanging data between views

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-web-ide

Actually I have a problem with exchanging data between views. i have a view that conatains a selectable table and i want to get the data of the selected rows and navigate to another view to do the treatement of these data (i've already done the navigation stuff) i just don't know how to create a global model or pass the data directly to the other view (i'm new to SAPUI5). Can anybody help me with that please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing Data Between Controllers While Navigating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48831967/passing-data-between-controllers-while-navigating)

Answer (score 3):

**Approach 1: Global model**

You can create global model in **component.js** or **App.controller.js**

[image]

and later you can assign data (selected record) to baseModel property like below

```
this.getView().getModel('baseModel').setProperty('/oSelectedRecord', data)
```

and in other view you can access that by below

```
this.getView().getModel('baseModel').getProperty('/oSelectedRecord')
```

**Approach 2: Routing with parameter**

Source view changes

[image]

Destination view changes

[image]

You can check detailed example in [walkthough](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.tutorial.walkthrough) (choose older version, in newer version you won't see much code details)